# Mysql server huge memory consumption

Tags: database-performance, mysql, database-tuning

On Ubuntu, executing the "top" command shows that mysqld constantly uses 61.9% of the memory.(when idle).
I ran "show processlist" on the mysql server and it is idle.
Can anyone explain what might be happening?

Answer (score 1):

Read this: http://www.chriscalender.com/?p=1278

Open my.cnf and add this at the end: performance_schema=0

Restart your services. From 620MB I have now 38MB memory used.